# (not) Loading of some avatars in chat

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat

Some avatars in chat don't load:

[image]

This happens in several browsers (IE / Chrome / FF)

https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1/sandbox

Comment: +1. Got this as well. FWIW, I can't see any error'd HTTP requests or JavaScript errors... it *seems* chat just doesn't bother trying to load them.

Comment: When I look in the network tab in Chrome, I don't even see it requesting the images that aren't loading.  Weird.  (also @SaladFruitcake - refreshing is not fixing for me).

Comment: Ok, so we lied, it *isn't* loading...but balpha's taking a look at it now.

Comment: @SaladFruitcake: Not for me...

Comment: Now that's what I call fast service @balpha!

Comment: Awesome to see this fixed!